# CURL - NodeJS Rest API call Imperva - [SyntaxError: Unexpected token <]

Tags: node.js, api, rest, curl, imperva

I have written a shell script code which is successfully adding a new OS Connection IP in Imperva system/instance.

```
## Create a new IP OS connection in a given site, server group.
create_ip()
{
 JSESSIONID="${1}"
 addThisIP="${2}"
 siteName="${3}"
 serverGroupName="${4}"
 echo -e "\n- Trying to create a new OS connection IP now.\n";

 ##Make sure while initiating a REST API call, any parameter which has ' ' (space) in Imperva should be substituted with '%20'.
 ##JSESSIONID will be generated first and will be available to this function
 create_new_ip_output="$(curl -ik -X POST -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=$JSESSIONID" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://${MX}:8083/SecureSphere/api/v1/conf/serverGroups/${siteName// /%20}/${serverGroupName// /%20}/servers/${addThisIP}" -d '{"connection-mode":"SSH","host-name":"thisLinuxServer.fdqn","OS-type":"linux","user-name":"enter_your_userID"}')";
 return_code="$?";
 if [[ "${return_code}" == "0" && ! `echo "${create_new_ip_output}" | grep "do not have permission"` ]]; then
  echo -e "\n\n- OS connection IP (${addThisIP}) created successfully in site: ${siteName}, servergroup: ${serverGroupName} and stdout:\n${create_new_ip_output}\n";
  return 0;
 else
  echo -e "\n\n- Failed to create a new OS connection IP (${addThisIP}) in site: ${siteName} and servergroup: ${serverGroupName}\n- using session ID: ${JSESSIONID}, error log:\n${create_new_ip_output}\n";
  return 1;
 fi
}
```

OK, the above code works fine and once run, I see valid output showing whether an IP got added successfully or what was the failure message.

Now, I'm trying to implement the same functionality in **NodeJS**.

To do that, I have successfully created functions to generate JSESSIONID (so that I can use it to perform multiple REST/API call operations, rather than creating a new session each time for any operation), successfully deleting a JSESSIONID (i.e. to logoff/out from Imperva session so that I don't hit the limit) and to successfully search an IP in Imperva system if it has been previously added.

Using the above shell script logic, I have written the following NodeJS code to add a new OS Connection IP in Imperva using Rest/API, but I'm getting an error.

```
//Imperva create IP
//qData is a hash array that has valid index/value pair values.
var impervaCreateIP = function(qData){
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var data = ''
  var options = {
    hostname: 'myImpervaServerInstance.mycompanydomain.com',
    port: 8083,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/SecureSphere/api/v1/conf/serverGroups/'+ qData['siteName'] + '/' + qData['serverGroupName'] + '/servers/' + qData['ip'],
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
      'X-Requested-With': 'Nodejs',
      'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID='+qData['sid']
    }
  }
  //svtLog() is a logger that I'm using to log messages to a file. Out of scope of this post.
  svtLog('info','Imperva','Inside impervaCreateIP function')
  svtLog('info','Imperva',qData['ip'])
  svtLog('info','Imperva',qData['siteName'])
  svtLog('info','Imperva',qData['serverGroupName'])
  svtLog('info','Imperva','')
  console.log('Inside impervaCreateIP')
  console.log(options);
  httpHelp(options, data)
  .then(function(fullResponse){
    var result = JSON.parse(fullResponse[1])
    console.log("11 -----")
    console.log(result)
    console.log("22 -----")
    deferred.resolve(qData['sid'])
    console.log(result)
  })
  .fail(function(e){
    svtLog('error','Imperva','Failed to add IP in Imperva')
    svtLog('info','Imperva',qData['ip'])
    svtLog('error','Imperva',e)
    svtLog('info','Imperva','')
    deferred.reject(e)
  })
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Inside impervaCreateIP
{ hostname: 'myImpervaServerInstance.mycompanydomain.com',
  port: 8083,
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/SecureSphere/api/v1/conf/serverGroups/some%20Site%20NameInImperva/someServerGroupNameInImperva_01/servers/10.20.30.40',
  headers: 
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
     'X-Requested-With': 'Nodejs',
     Cookie: 'JSESSIONID=7B3C378D365B673F6C749847DEDC7D8F } }
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token <]
```

**I'm looking for 2 things:**
1. How to resolve the error (as shown above).
2. How to pass CURL's **-d option {...}** body parameters in the NodeJS code above, like I used it in the shell script.

**PS**: Changing POST to GET (method), assures that the code is fine syntax wise as it successfully shows the IP (with GET operation) with the above NodeJS code.

So, it's **failing** only when I use **POST** (i.e. when I'm trying to create an IP) -vs- GET (which I use to find an IP exist or not). I checked as per the Imperva API doc, the response comes in JSON format. *Not sure if due to missing bullet# 2 question, I'm getting this Syntax error with POST.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.

Solution to both bullet# 1 and #2 was to set the CURL "-d option values" in NodeJS like shown below (I was setting it blank earlier):

```
  var data = '{"connection-mode":"SSH","host-name":"thisLinuxServer.fdqn","OS-type":"linux","user-name":"enter_your_userID"}'
```

Now, both options and data will be sent to httpHelp(options,data) and it'll work.

The above is just an dummy data value. Usually I'd pass valid host-name in the JSON object.

Never thought that not setting the data variable would result in this syntax error.

Other thing, I was missing BIG time was the value for 'Content-Type' inside headers variable. That was the reason, the error message was having "<" bracket in it (as by default it looks for a **`<body>...</body>`** section containing some **XML format** but in our case, the HTML response contained or was getting returned in JSON **{ ... }** format way for the body section. That's why it was showing an error for **unexpected token <**.

As per the API doc, it should have been "JSON" type, thus changed that line to

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```